# What are the parameters passed to cvFindContours() in JavaCV?

Tags: java, c++, opencv

Please can some one explain about `cvFindContours` method and what are the parameters that it required?

For example, here's code using OpenCV:

```
hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Please can some one explain how to write this using JavaCV?

Comment: I don't know about javacv but for the parameters take a look at [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=#cv2.findContours)

Comment: In JavaCV it contains following format for method cvFindContours(opencv_core.CvArr cvarr, opencv_core.CvMemStorage cms, opencv_core.CvSeq cvseq, int i, int i1, int i2). So what does this 3 integers means ?

Comment: this seems to be similar to opencv 1.x interface: `int cvFindContours(CvArr* image, CvMemStorage* storage, CvSeq** first_contour, int header_size=sizeof(CvContour), int mode=CV_RETR_LIST, int method=CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, CvPoint offset=cvPoint(0,0) )`

Comment: Also, read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668573/find-contours-in-javacv-or-opencv) for reference...

Comment: But in there for 3rd integer it can't pass cvPoint reference. Because it ask to pass integer.

Comment: @SL_User `i -> header_size, i1 -> mode, i2 -> method`

Comment: @Mohammad : Ohh Thnaks I just saw it. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As comments mentioned by Mohammad those three parameters are **header_size**, **mode** and **method**. You can use this method as follows

```
    IplImage src = cvLoadImage(path);//hear path is actual path to image
    IplImage grayImage    = IplImage.create(src.width(), src.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvCvtColor(src, grayImage, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    cvThreshold(grayImage, grayImage, 127, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    CvSeq cvSeq=new CvSeq();
    CvMemStorage memory=CvMemStorage.create();
    cvFindContours(grayImage, memory, cvSeq, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Hope this might help you to understand this method.