# Find X,Y in image using Opencv (Javacv)

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I'm having a problem getting the x,y cords for an object in an image.

I am using Javacv, and so far, I have the image, and converted it into HSV, and afterwards used the inRange functions to get a B/W edition of the image.

The point now, is that if there is a red object on the picture, I would like to get the x,y coords of this, and possibly save these into an array or something like that.

I hope you can understand my question/problem. I not, feel free to ask, and i'll try to explain better.

/Jesper

Comment: well, in c++, i'd have done the same steps as you did, and then apply findContours() on the binarized image, which gives you a list of outlines. maybe you can find a javacv demo for that ?

Comment: Hmm that could work, however I read about a function called Moments and spatialMoments in the opencv lib, which might help me. I just don't fully understand these functions.

Comment: moments are a similar idea. they don't give you outlines, but information about shape, like the area, grade of elongation, curviness. unfortunately, that works's only for 1 item, afaik

Comment: Alright, well if they only work for 1 item then that won't work in my case.

Comment: I have now tried the findContours, however I don't see what to do now. Should I use some of the variables memory, or cvSeq to get the position of the contours? I've done like this example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374400/what-are-the-parameters-passed-to-cvfindcontours-in-javacv

Comment: cvSeq seems to be the one, in c++ it's a 'vector<vector<Point>>` so a list of contour points for each contour found.  there's drawContours, and minAreaRect but bear with me for not knowing javacv

Comment: Your help is much appreciated! :)